# Adding a second $_GET tag to URL breaks MySQL ORDER BY clause

Tags: php, html, mysql

In the first iteration of my database project for school I successfully created a page that will sort a MySQL table when clicking on the headers of each table column by using a `$_GET` tag. The first time around I created a separate page for each main entry in the database table I was accessing.

For the second iteration I chose to use one page that would display the same information as before but would select from the database when linking to the page using `$_GET` tags, instead.

I'm trying to figure out why the following code will correctly sort the table I'm displaying:

```
    $query = "SELECT Review.username, Review.service_date, Review.review_date, 
            Review.review_rating, Review.review_details, Review.service_id,
            Plumber.company_name
            FROM Review
            INNER JOIN Plumber
            ON Review.service_id = Plumber.service_id
            WHERE Plumber.service_id='1'";
            
    if ($_GET['sort'] == 'username') {
        $query .= " ORDER BY username";
    } else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'service_date') {
        $query .= " ORDER BY service_date DESC";
    } else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'review_date') {
        $query .= " ORDER BY review_date DESC";
    } else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'review_rating') {
        $query .= " ORDER BY review_rating DESC";
    } else {
        $query .= " ORDER BY review_date";
    }

    $response = @mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $plumber;
    
    if($response){
        echo '<table align="left" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8" width="50%">
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber1.php?sort=username">Username</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber1.php?sort=service_date">Service Date</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber1.php?sort=review_date">Review Date</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber1.php?sort=review_rating">Review Rating</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Review Details</b></td>';
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
            echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
            $row['username'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['service_date'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['review_date'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['review_rating'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['review_details'] . '</td>';
    
            echo '</tr>';
            
            $plumber = $row['company_name'];
        }
        
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
        echo mysqli_error($db);
    }
```

When this code wont:

```
    $query2 = "SELECT Review.username, Review.service_date, Review.review_date, 
            Review.review_rating, Review.review_details, Review.service_id,
            Plumber.company_name
            FROM Review
            INNER JOIN Plumber
            ON Review.service_id = Plumber.service_id
            WHERE Plumber.service_id='$plumber_id'";
            
    $response2 = @mysqli_query($db, $query2);
            
    if ($_GET['sort'] == 'username') {
        $query2 .= " ORDER BY username";
    } else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'service_date') {
        $query2 .= " ORDER BY service_date DESC";
    } else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'review_date') {
        $query2 .= " ORDER BY review_date DESC";
    } else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'review_rating') {
        $query2 .= " ORDER BY review_rating DESC";
    } else {
        $query2 .= " ORDER BY username";
    }
    
    if ($response2) {
        
        echo '<table align="left" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8" width="50%">
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber.php?id='.$plumber_id.'&sort=username">Username</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber.php?id='.$plumber_id.'&sort=service_date">Service Date</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber.php?id='.$plumber_id.'&sort=review_date">Review Date</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><a href="Plumber.php?id='.$plumber_id.'&sort=review_rating">Review Rating</a></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b>Review Details</b></td>';
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response2)) {
            echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
            $row['username'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['service_date'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['review_date'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['review_rating'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['review_details'] . '</td>';
    
            echo '</tr>';
            
            $plumber = $row['company_name'];
        }
        
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
        echo mysqli_error($db);
    }
```

The only differences between the two pages is instead of statically defining the variable in the WHERE clause of my SQL query, I pass it a value pulled from the `$_GET` tag and I renamed a view variables.

Adding `'$query2 .= " ORDER BY var";'` immediately after defining $query2 will successfully sort the table by whatever row I use for var. I've used a `header('location: url')` within each line of the if block I used to determine which value for `$_GET['sort']` is being passed in to ensure each line is being reached and it's successfully redirecting for each one.

Anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? My professor (and therefore me too) isn't worried about proper practices like using prepared statements and the like - it just needs to be functional. I'm just trying to figure out what broke.

Sorry for the novel and if I'm breaking some rule, this is my first time posting here

[Here's what the table looks like for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29siT.png)

Comment: if you print the generated queries you will be able to spot the problem easily

Comment: How would I do that? I'm a complete newbie at PHP, I had to teach myself everything over the last week

Comment: `echo $query, "<br>", $query2`

Comment: print $query :)

Comment: I don't know php but looks like in the second example you append the sort to the sql query after you have executed it?

Comment: Actually that was it. Thanks David. I've been doing this for going on 8 hours straight, I'm a tad tired and finding these errors has been getting harder :)

Comment: @DavidB You're sharp! :)

Comment: @tmpka - no worries, sometimes a new pair of eyes is all it takes

Answer (score 0):

I have escaped your variable. This will fix query issues most of the time.

```
$query2 = "SELECT Review.username, Review.service_date, Review.review_date, 
        Review.review_rating, Review.review_details, Review.service_id,
        Plumber.company_name
        FROM Review
        INNER JOIN Plumber
        ON Review.service_id = Plumber.service_id
        WHERE Plumber.service_id='".$plumber_id."'";



$response2 = @mysqli_query($db, $query2);
```

This is just a beaty suggestion:

```
switch ($_GET['osrt']) {
    case 'something':
        $query = "";
        break
    case 'somethingelse':
        $query = "";
        break;
    default:
        $query = "";
        break;
}
```